# Saving Paginated child only when Parent get saved in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, activerecord, nested-attributes, object-lifetime

I have application with form containing Parents with its Child rendered through Nested Attributes in view for edit.

Take example of Hr trying to edit an employee details along with his skill ratings. The page render employee detail along with his skillsets in paginated form.

Today when HR edit the first page of skillsets and set request for second page of skillset, I save the modified skillset on the first page in DB and render the second page in view for Edit.

But here the requirement is that, I should not save the first page data when moving to next page, but only when user click the save button on the employee.

I know that, I can save the first page data in temporary storage like Redis and when HR click save, I get the updated details of previous pages from it and save all the childs at once along with the save of employee.

What is the cleanest way of achieving this ?

I do not want to write my custom logic for this, like persisting the previous page in Redis, Then tracking if the page user requesting is available in Redis or not, if not fetching from DB otherwise rendering from Redis and finally looping over the updated child and save along with the parent.

Comment: You could render the 2 pages at once and change pages using javascript (hide one div, show the other) instead of a complete request to the server and only do a request on submit. Another option can be to render all the data from the first page as hidden inputs when you render the second page, so the submit will include all the data.

Comment: @arieljuod all these possibility I already have but do not look scalable to me. Think of case where we have say 1000 child. Loading all of them in DOM as hidden field will slow down the page response severely. As I told I can manage it through my custom solution by storing the previous page data temporarily in Redis. But what I want to know that is there something which Rails provide for this Use case which I am not aware of.